# Install SublimeHighlight plugin on Sublime Text 3

Tags: terminal, python, text-editor, git, sublimetext

I'm trying to copy my code from Sublime Text 3 into my Word document in RTF format with colors in tact by using this plugin:

https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight

The instructions say:

> Sublime Text 3 users: a `python3` branch is also available. Just `git
>   checkout python3` from the root of your package installation to use in
>   in ST3. If you upgrade from a previous ST2 installation or encounter
>   problems with the package, please proceed as detailed below:
>
> - Remove the package, if installed, using Package Control.
> - Add a repository: `https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight/tree/python3`
> - Install `SublimeHighlight` with Package Control. It should pull the correct branch from Github.
> - Restart Sublime Text 3

Well...I'm a noob when it comes to all the stuff it's describing. I went to `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/MacOS` and ran `git checkout python3` but got `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. I think I need to install git? Or Python3? I'm not sure exactly where to start or even if this git stuff is worth Googling, as I'm not even sure if I'm running the command in the correct directory or even if the plugin indeed is compatible with MacOS (even though their screenshots of using the plugin on Sublime Text 2 are in MacOS on the GitHub ReadMe...)

I would greatly appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432069/3511695

> 1. Install Package Control inside sublime text 3. If you don't know how, follow this link [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)
> 2. Open the Sublime Command Pallette by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+P on Windows and ⌘⇧P on Mac
> 3. Type "Add Repository", and press enter or return
>
> Then paste this link
>   https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight/tree/python3 [and press
>   enter]
>
> 4. Press CTRL+SHIFT+P on Windows and ⌘⇧P on Mac again and type "Install package" and press enter or return
> 5. Type "Sublime highlight" and press enter to install the plugin
> 6. Restart your Sublime